# use for loop to visit all elements in a HashSet (Java)?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, hashset

I have write the code as:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        HashSet<Integer> has1 = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(nums1)); 
        for (int i: has1)
            System.out.println(i);
        return nums1;
    }
}

num1: [1,2,4,2,3]
num2: [4,5,6,3]
```

On the for loop it says `java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455737/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-hashset-without-a-iterator

Comment: `int` and `Integer` are not the same type.  Fix the type in the `for` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have write this code based on the idea. However there is an error in my code. I want to know how to fix it.

Comment: You need something like `new HashSet<>(IntStream.of(nums1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))`, you're currently getting a `HashSet<int[]>` and using a raw-type so you're also ignoring a warning.

Comment: @4castle [Raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Frisch, Thank you very much!!! It works!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot do this directly but you need to prefer a indirect approach

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int value : a) {
            set.add(value);
        }
        for (Integer i : set) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

using Java 8

```
 1) Set<Integer> newSet = IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());//recomended

    2)  IntStream.of(a).boxed().forEach(i-> System.out.println(i)); //applicable
```

here first `foreach` is sufficient for you and If you want to go by set, go with second for loop

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is containing `Integer` objects, so while iterating through foreach loop, you should write `for (Integer i : collection)` - that is because primitive type `int` do not have its own `Iterator` implementation.