# Retrieving data from database and using that data for getting some more data

Tags: java, jdbc, hashset

I am retrieving tables from database. I am using the following code:

```
HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<String>();
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {   
    hash.add(rs.getString(3));
}
```

I am getting each table twice as the output of this code. I am retrieving through hashset, but still I am getting each table twice. I want each table only one time.

Secondly, I want to use the tables stored in hashset to retrieve data from database. Which I am doing like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hash.size(); i++) {
    sql="Select distinct a from hash.get(i)";
    //now passing this to prepared statement and as usual taking resultset
}
```

But I run my application it shows that this does not exist, even when table is present in database. Please help me with both these scenarios.

Comment: This cannot be your actual code as this won't even compile. Post some actual code as there's no reason to invesigate the fake code you came up with.

Comment: I have added the part of code in which I am getting problem and this is not a fake one..

Comment: `hash.add(rs,getString(3))` - This. Will. Not. Compile. This cannot be real code.

Comment: I have edited it please have a look

Comment: Show an example of which values does your set contain.

Comment: Are you passing this string to the prepared statement: "Select distinct a from hash.get(i)" o it's just a typo?

Comment: a_employee_raw, a_employee_raw..this should come only once..this table and other tables re coming twice

Comment: Did you try to display each column of your result, it could help, there must be something different.

Comment: You set can't hold duplicate values. Somehow these values are different. Find out how.

Comment: Perhaps the connection has access to multiple schemas and the tables are defined in multiple schemas?  Also, HashSet.get() doesn't exist.

Comment: @andrew I think you are right,,,how I can get tables from one schema and how to retreive data from tables present in hashset

Comment: Add the schema parameter to narrow the search: `md.getTables(null, "{schemaOfInterest}", "%", null)` or change the user of the connection to only have access to the schema.  And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455737/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-hashset-without-an-iterator) to iterate over a Set.

Comment: One more doubt how to add schema.. Could you please show with example to add user defined tables from schema